# Get labels for all checked inputs and append to html (for each)

Tags: jquery

I have multiple checkboxes with labels on a page. For each checkbox that is checked I want to append the label to a div (comma separated). When one of the checkbox is unchecked I want to remove that specific label from the div. The number of checkboxes can be variable.

What I have so far:

```js
  $("input:checkbox").click(function() {
      var selected = $("label[for='" + this.id + "']").text() + ',';
      $("p").html(selected); 
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>

<input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" />
<label for="checkbox1">checkbox label</label>
```

With this code I can append one of checked checkboxes labels to the html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) [`:checked`](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) checkboxes then use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/)and get the  label text in an array.

```js
//Cache selectors
var elem = $("input:checkbox"); 

//Bind change event
elem.change(function() {
  var selected = elem
  .filter(':checked') //Filter only checked checkboxes
  .map(function() {
    return $("label[for='" + this.id + "']").text();
  })
  .get(); //Get array
  
  $("p").html(selected.join(','));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>

<input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" />
<label for="checkbox1">checkbox label</label>
<br/>
<input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" />
<label for="checkbox2">checkbox label 2</label>
```

Comment: great answer, when you say "Cache elements", what and how exactly it's working as cache element

Comment: @Loading.. A good read https://ttmm.io/tech/selector-caching-jquery/ and correct term is `cache selectors`

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is based on:

- when a checkbox changes value the event is [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) and not click
- when a checkbox change state the paragraph content must be updated
- in order to select checkbox you may use: [:checkbox Selector](https://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/)
- in order to filter only the checked elements you may use [:checked Selector](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)
- [empty the paragrapgh](https://api.jquery.com/empty/)
- [for each](https://api.jquery.com/each/)  checked element [append](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) the label text.

My snippet:

```js
$(":checkbox").on('change', function(e) {
  $("p").empty();
  $(":checkbox:checked").each(function(i, e) {
    var selectedLblText = $("label[for='" + this.id + "']").text();
    $("p").html(function(index, oldhtml) {
      return (oldhtml == '') ? selectedLblText : oldhtml + ', ' + selectedLblText;
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p></p>
<form>
    <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox"/>
    <label for="checkbox1">checkbox label</label><br>
    <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox"/>
    <label for="checkbox2">checkbox labe2</label><br>
    <input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox"/>
    <label for="checkbox3">checkbox labe3</label>
</form>
```

Comment: It is not necessary to use array and `.push()` while all texts should puted next to each other.